# Does std::unordered_map operator[] do zero-initialization for non-exisiting key?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, zero-initialization

According to cppreference.com, [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) for non-existing value does zero-initialization.

However, the same site does not mention zero-initialization for [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), except it does have an example which relies on this.

Of course this is just a reference site, not the standard. So, is the code below ok or not?

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    return map[42];     // is this guaranteed to return 0?
}
```

Comment: @Ælex you cannot reliably test if something is initialized

Comment: @Ælex I dont really understand, how can you have a non-initialized `std::optional`?

Comment: @Ælex there is no way to test if an object is initialized or not because any operation on an uninitialized object other than initialization results in Undefined Behavior. A `std::optional` object that holds no contained value is still an initialized object.

Comment: The value object is value-initialized, not zero-initialized. For scalar types these are the same, but for class types they are different.

Comment: @bolov I tried to test it yesterday using gnu 17 and std 17, and bizarrely all I got was zero initialisation. I thought `std::optional` `has_value` would test it but it fails, so I guess you are correct.

Comment: @Ælex In that test, what did you do to ensure that the memory location where your `std::optional` was placed was in a already used memory page, *and* that memory location was also previously set to something else than zero? Or did you inspect the produced assembly and noticed it explicitly writes zeroes there?

Comment: @hyde I intentionally left an uninitialised variable and tried wrapping it with `std::optional` and I think the compiler optimised it to zero. I did not go into the debugger, but could give it a try.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on which overload we're talking about, `std::unordered_map::operator[]` is equivalent to [[unord.map.elem]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map.elem)

```
T& operator[](const key_type& k)
{
    return try_­emplace(k).first->second;
}
```

(the overload taking an rvalue-reference just moves `k` into `try_emplace` and is otherwise identical)

If an element exists under key `k` in the map, then `try_emplace` returns an iterator to that element and `false`. Otherwise, `try_emplace` inserts a new element under the key `k`, and returns an iterator to that and `true` [[unord.map.modifiers]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map.modifiers):

```cpp
template <class... Args>
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace(const key_type& k, Args&&... args);
```

Interesting for us is the case of there being no element yet [[unord.map.modifiers]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map.modifiers#6):

> Otherwise inserts an object of type `value_­type` constructed with `piecewise_­construct, forward_­as_­tuple(k), forward_­as_­tuple(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`

(the overload taking an rvalue-reference just moves `k` into `forward_­as_­tuple` and, again, is otherwise identical)

Since `value_type` is a `pair<const Key, T>` [[unord.map.overview]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map#overview-2), this tells us that the new map element will be constructed as:

```cpp
pair<const Key, T>(piecewise_­construct, forward_­as_­tuple(k), forward_­as_­tuple(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...));
```

Since `args` is empty when coming from `operator[]`, this boils down to our new value being constructed as a member of the `pair` from no arguments [[pairs.pair]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/pairs#pair-14) which is direct initialization [[class.base.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#7) of a value of type `T` using `()` as initializer which boils down to value initialization [[dcl.init]/17.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.4). Value initialization of an `int` is zero initialization [[dcl.init]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#8). And zero initialization of an `int` naturally initializes that `int` to 0 [[dcl.init]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#6).

So yes, your code is guaranteed to return 0…

Comment: So good (and friendly) I'd upboat twice if I could. Thankya

Answer (score 24):

On the site you linked it says:

> When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy
>   constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.

So the `int` is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> [...]
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

This is why the result is `0`.